# Linq query to select distinct record and count number of distinct record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have table `tblVisitor` which stores visitors location details. It has below structure.

```
vRegion      NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
vTimeZone    NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
vLat         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL, //Latitude
vLong        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL, //Longitude
```

Now, this storage depends on each `session` and when the `session` expires the same location details might be stored again. Now I am trying to display this in a Map and thus am getting Latitude and Longitude details in a model class. My model class is as below:

```
public class VisitorMapViewModel
{
    public int count { get; set;}
    public GeoCoordinate coords { get; set; }
}
```

Am trying to fill model as below, but with no luck.

```
List<VisitorMapViewModel> model = new List<VisitorMapViewModel>();
var data = _db.tblVisitors.Distinct().ToList().Select(v => new VisitorMapViewModel()
            {
                coords = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(v.vLat), Convert.ToDouble(v.vLong)),
                count = _db.tblVisitors.GroupBy(m => new { m.vLat,m.vLong}).Select(m=>m).Distinct().Count()
            }).ToList();
```

There are 2 problems here.. Converting `Latitude` and `Longitude` values of type `nvarchar` to `double` and then getting distinct values of latitude and longitude and counting the number of occurances.. The above query keeps hitting one or other kind of exception when I interchange converting to `ToList()` before `Distinct()` and vice versa.. I feel am almost near, but not sure what am missing. Could anyone help on this please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do one query that groups on the latitude and longitude and gets the counts.  Then convert the results into your model.  You can use `AsEnumerable` when you want to switch from SQL queries to in memory Linq queries without needing the overhead of creating a list.

```
var data = (from visitor in _db.tblVisitors
            group visitor by new { visitor.vLat, visitor.vLong } into grp
            select new 
            {
                grp.Key.vLat,
                grp.Key.vLong,
                Count = grp.Count()
            })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new new VisitorMapViewModel()
        {
            coords = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(
                double.Parse(x.vLat), 
                double.Parse(x.vLong)),
            count = x.Count
        })
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively you could do this all in method syntax

```
var data = _db.tblVisitors
    .GroupBy(v => new { v.vLat, v.vLong })
    .Select(grp => new 
        {
            grp.Key.vLat,
            grp.Key.vLong,
            Count = grp.Count()
        })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new new VisitorMapViewModel()
        {
            coords = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(
                double.Parse(x.vLat), 
                double.Parse(x.vLong)),
            count = x.Count
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Great.. Works like charm.. One last question.. Which one in the above ways would you suggest using when performance and memory comes into picture?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao They are literally the same as far as performance and memory is concerned.  It's more of a question of style.  The first one makes it more obvious that the first part is Linq that will be converted to SQL IMO, but the second does look "cleaner".

Comment: Nice.. Thanks much again... Happy coding.. I don't know why people downvote inspite of showing what we have tried and trying to post a good question IMHO..